# Add class containing spesific text in class name

Tags: javascript, css

I downloaded a CSS file which looks like this (first few lines)

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon-3dm-file-format:before {
    content: "\f100";
}
```

Problem is that not all file extension classes are written in the same way.

```
.flaticon-3gp-file-format-variant:before {
    content: "\f103";
}
```

One class looks like this for example

```
$(myelement).addClass('flaticon-' + extension + '-file-format');
```

So this line of code only works sometimes.

Is there a way to find and add the spesific class containing `flaticon` and `extension-type` in jQuery?

Comment: `$(myelement).addClass('flaticon-' + extension + '-file-format');` will do what you require. What's the problem?

Comment: Does not work with `flaticon-3gp-file-format-variant`

Comment: @PerPettersen on what condition do you want to add the different classes?

Answer (score 1):

What ever is used in CSS selectors can be used with Jquery selectors too..

So all you need is

```
$('[class^="flaticon-"][class*="-file-format"]')
```

- `[class^="flaticon-"]` -> Select all the elements with class starting (^) with `flaticon-`
- `[class*="-file-format"]` -> Select all the elements with class having `-file-format` anywhere (*) in the name

So when you combine them it means select a element which has a class that starts with `flaticon-` and has `-file-format` after it anywhere.

So this will select both your elements with class

`.flaticon-3dm-file-format` and `flaticon-3gp-file-format-variant`

Comment: As I understood, he's asking how to know which class to add to a specific element, not how to select those classes, which are two completely different things.

Comment: @Imaginaroom This statement `Is there a way to find and add the spesific class containing flaticon and extension-type in jQuery?` doesnt seem to mean so..

Comment: To find which one it is to add, because he doesn't know does it contain -variant or not, have you seen his example? $(myelement).addClass('flaticon-' + extension + '-file-format');

Comment: @Imaginaroom but if he doesnt know when to add `-variant` and when to not, then the question itself is not clear. I agree with your point though

Comment: The question is clear. The question is about that how to know when to add it or not. That is the problem

Comment: `how to know when to add it or not` How to know? on what condition can you judge that? has he given the condition?

Comment: @Imaginaroom Can you tell me the condition on which I can decide when to add which format of the classes

Comment: I don't know, that is his problem as I understand. :D

Comment: @Imaginaroom then how did you tell `The question is clear` ?

Comment: The question is clear as in a way that it is easy to understand what he wants, I didn't say I have the solution. :P

Comment: The question is clear if all the details are given. Else its unclear. :)